# How to differentiate two uilocalnotification inside application didRecieveLocalNotification and fire corresponding alert in ios?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

In my app i am scheduling two UILocalNotification,one is fired depending on the time selected in UIDatePicker and other on repeat Interval basis.The problem here is i have to fire two different alert for both when user tap on the notification.How can i distinguish these two notification and fire corresponding alert .

Answer (score 1):

Part of the UILocalNotification object you will get there is a userInfo property. Set a key like "type" to values like "main" and "repeat" to differentiate the notification.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by repeat interval basic. Are you talking about the notification for the snooze functionality. If that is the case then you dont have to set the second notification for repeat interval at the time of setting the original notification. You can set the repeat interval notification only when the original notification is fired.

Besides you can set the setUserInfo attribute of the notification object.

```
[localNotification setUserInfo:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Snoozed", kSnoozedAlarm, nil]];
```

You can give your notification a unique name in order to distinguish it from the others.

You can then iterate through the scheduledLocalNotifications to search for the specific notification.

```
    NSArray *arrayNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayNotifications count]; i++)
    {
        UILocalNotification *snoozedNotification = [arrayNotifications objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *userInfo = snoozedNotification.userInfo;
        if ([[userInfo objectForKey:kSnoozedAlarm] isEqualToString:@"Snoozed"])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:snoozedNotification];
        }
    }
```

You can use the below code in order to repeat the alert.

```
[localNotification setRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit];
```